# Какие шрифты есть в каждой ОС по умолчанию?

Tags: python, шрифты

Просто названия. Мне нужны TrueType шрифты для моего проэкта на python pygame
которые pygame может использовать функцией `pygame.font.SysFont(название, размер)`

Comment: Скорее всего таких нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- font-family: (шрифт без засечек), Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
- font-family: (шрифт с засечками), "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
- font-family: (моноширинный шрифт), "Courier New", Courier, monospaced;

[habrahabr.ru](https://habrahabr.ru/post/25958/)

Comment: Это вы сейчас про CSS? Совершенно не факт, что Times, например, гарантированно окажется в любой ОС, кроме Windows

Comment: @m9-psy, по моим тестам в Linux он тоже есть.